# When the null conditional operator short-circuits, does it still evaluate method arguments?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

The null conditional operator can be used to skip method calls on a null target. Would the method arguments be evaluated or not in that case?

For example:

```
myObject?.DoSomething(GetFromNetwork());
```

Is `GetFromNetwork` called when `myObject` is `null`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They will not be evaluated.

```
class C
{
    public void Method(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method");
    }
}

static int GetSomeValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetSomeValue");
    return 0;
}

C c = null;
c?.Method(GetSomeValue());
```

This does not print anything. Resharper marks the evaluation of `GetSomeValue()`as dead code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject?.Method();
```

is basically equivalent to

```
var temp = myObject;
if (temp != null) {
    temp.Method();
}
```

You see that no argument can be evaluated if `myObject` is `null`.

Note that if you replaced `myObject` by

Comment: They are not equivalent. Specifically, the former evaluates `object` only once, the latter twice if non-`null`. Since they're not equivalent, no conclusions should be drawn from it.

Comment: @hvd They are. It is stated as this even in the specs (*literally!*). And since it is a variable, there is no double evaluation. https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/expressions.md#member-access

Comment: They are not in general, as stated in the very specs you link to: "except that P is evaluated only once.", later "except that P is evaluated only once.", yet later "except that P is evaluated only once.", finally "Except that a.b and a.b[0] are evaluated only once." and "except that a.b and a.b[0] are evaluated only once." Yes, for a local variable, double evaluation does not change the results. The part that this is the *only* exception would be a good addition to your answer, IMO.